# Unknow column in a MySQLTrigger execution

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I have this trigger with no syntax errors working on my DB:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS image_demand;
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER image_demand BEFORE INSERT ON demand_img
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE val DATE DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE minValue CURSOR FOR SELECT min(date_demand) AS RES FROM demand_img;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE; 

    OPEN minValue;
    read_loop : LOOP
        FETCH minValue INTO val;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE minValue;
    IF minValue IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET NEW.date_demand = val + INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
    END IF;
END //
```

It tries to add 1 hour from the minimum value already setted in the database, to the new register about to insert. But when I try to insert a new image_demand component with an INSERT command, it fails with this error:

```
18:16:40    INSERT INTO `database`.`demand_img` (USER_ID_FK, IMG_ID) VALUES (2, 'asdfasdfasdfa')    
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'minValue' in 'field list' 0.000 sec
```

As you can see, **minValue** is a variable that comes from the Trigger, so I think the error is from it, but I can't see where is it. Maybe am I setting minValue incorrectly?

Thank you for your help

J.

Comment: Just a side note, but you should not need a cursor for that.

Comment: Is it possible to assign directly for an unique result?

Comment: Yes, my MySQL is a bit rusty, but it should be something like `SELECT MIN(date_demand) INTO val FROM demand_img` or `SET val = (SELECT MIN...)`; cursors tend to be relatively expensive, so should generally be used very rarely. If you're using a cursor, and not sure you need it, you probably don't.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see my mistake. Sorry for bugging you. IF minValue should be IF val

MySQL compiles it without showing any error.

Sorry and thank you.